# How can I login into my heroku account ? Unable to access my account due to Multi Factor Authentication

Tags: authentication, heroku, account, google-authenticator

Please Help!

- I am unable to login into my heroku account even I know my correct login id and password due to the 2FA which was enabled mistakenly with me because I needed to deploy my app quickly.
- I used Google Authenticator for generating the authentication code and logged in but next day my mobile got damaged in a way which couldn't be repaired. Due to which when again I tried to login it still asks for google generated verification code which I don't have, I contacted heroku support several times but it's been a month but still I couldn't get any satisfactory response.

They have opened some Temporary code login and provided a recovery code but still I am unable to login.
Anyone Please help me get my account
[Page where I am stuck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CO6EC.png)